# I have 3 types of search but it do dusplication

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a 3 types of search

- by governorate
- by district
- by city

  each time the user select governorate the system display the right answers

but if the user choose district it duplicate the result that mean it show the same result of governorate and that one related to the selected district  or village

but what i want is to just display the user that have the selected district or governorate or village not all

## code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['listbyq']))
    {    
    //********************by governorate**************************************//
       if($_POST['listbyq']=="by_gov")
       {
           $bygov = $_POST['governorate'];
           $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
        s.specialization_name,
        g.governorate_name,
        d.district_name,
        v.village_name 
              FROM members u
                           INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                            ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                            INNER JOIN governorate g
                            ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                            INNER JOIN districts d
                            ON u.district = d.district_id
                            INNER JOIN village v
                            ON u.village = v.id
                            WHERE governorate = '$bygov'")or die(mysql_error("Error: querying the governorate"));
           
           $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
           if($num_row > 0 )
           {
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
               {
                  $row_id = $row['user_id'];
                  $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
                  $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
                  $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
                  $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
                  $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];
                  $row_gov = $row['governorate_name'];
                  $row_dist = $row['district_name'];
                  $row_village = $row['village_name'];
                  
                    ////***********for the upload image*************************//
             $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
             $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
             if(file_exists($check_pic))
             {
                 $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
             }
             else
             {
                 $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
             }
              
              $outputlist.='
         <table width="100%">
                     <tr>
                        <td width="23%" rowspan="5"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                        <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                        <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                          <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                          <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Job:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Location:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_gov.'__'.$row_dist.'__'.$row_village.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <hr />
                ';
                  
               }
           }
           
       }
       else
       {
           $errorMSG = "No member within this selected governorate";
       }
     //*****************************by District***************************************//  
       if($_POST['listbyqa']=="by_dist")
       {
          @ $bydist = $_POST['district'];
           $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
        s.specialization_name,
        g.governorate_name,
        d.district_name,
        v.village_name 
              FROM members u
                           INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                            ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                            INNER JOIN governorate g
                            ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                            INNER JOIN districts d
                            ON u.district = d.district_id
                            INNER JOIN village v
                            ON u.village = v.id
                           WHERE district = '$bydist'")or die(mysql_error("Error: querying the district"));
           
           $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
           if($num_row > 0 )
           {
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
               {
                  $row_id = $row['user_id'];
                  $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
                  $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
                  $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
                  $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
                  $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];
                  $row_gov = $row['governorate_name'];
                  $row_dist = $row['district_name'];
                  $row_village = $row['village_name'];
                  
                    ////***********for the upload image*************************//
             $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
             $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
             if(file_exists($check_pic))
             {
                 $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
             }
             else
             {
                 $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
             }
              
              $outputlist.='
         <table width="100%">
                     <tr>
                        <td width="23%" rowspan="5"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                        <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                        <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                          <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                          <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Job:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Location:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_gov.'__'.$row_dist.'__'.$row_village.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <hr />
                ';
                  
               }
           }
           
       }
       else
       {
           $errorMSG = "No member within this selected District";
       } 
    
    //****************************by Village**************************************//
    if($_POST['listbyqb']=="by_city")
       {
          @ $byvillage = $_POST['village'];
           $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
        s.specialization_name,
        g.governorate_name,
        d.district_name,
        v.village_name 
              FROM members u
                           INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                            ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                            INNER JOIN governorate g
                            ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                            INNER JOIN districts d
                            ON u.district = d.district_id
                            INNER JOIN village v
                            ON u.village = v.id
                           WHERE village = '$byvillage'")or die(mysql_error("Error: querying the district"));
           
           $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
           if($num_row > 0 )
           {
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
               {
                  $row_id = $row['user_id'];
                  $row_first_name =  $row['first_name'];
                  $row_last_name =  $row['last_name'];
                  $row_birthdate =  $row['birth_date'];
                  $row_registered_date = $row['registered_date'];
                  $row_spec = $row['specialization_name'];
                  $row_gov = $row['governorate_name'];
                  $row_dist = $row['district_name'];
                  $row_village = $row['village_name'];
                  
                    ////***********for the upload image*************************//
             $check_pic="members/$row_id/image01.jpg";
             $default_pic="members/0/image01.jpg";
             if(file_exists($check_pic))
             {
                 $user_pic="<img src=\"$check_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
             }
             else
             {
                 $user_pic="<img src=\"$default_pic\"width=\"120px\"/>";
             }
              
              $outputlist.='
         <table width="100%">
                     <tr>
                        <td width="23%" rowspan="5"><div style="height:120px;overflow:hidden;"><a href =              "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$user_pic.'</a></div></td>
                        <td width="14%"><div  align="right">Name:</div></td>
                        <td width="63%"><a href = "http://localhost/newadamKhoury/profile.php?user_id='.$row_id.'" target="_blank">'.$row_first_name.' '.$row_last_name.'</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                          <td><div align="right">Birth date:</div></td>
                          <td>'.$row_birthdate.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Registered:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_registered_date.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Job:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_spec.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                         <td><div align="right">Location:</div></td>
                         <td>'.$row_gov.'__'.$row_dist.'__'.$row_village.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <hr />
                ';
                  
               }
           }
           
       }
       else
       {
           $errorMSG = "No member within this selected District";
       }
    }

?>
```

Comment: check what value is being passed in listbyqb by echoing it.

Comment: There are SQL injection holes in your code. Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: Show us tables structures and 3 queries, you are executing. We don't want to waste time, reading your irrelevant HTML and php code. If you want people to answer your question, prepare it in such a way, so they could easily read it and understand, what's the problem.

Comment: @ user 4035  OK but without beating me   but these are the 3 queries and the fetching with the display of html to make you understand what it look my sceene when it display results

Comment: @user2396708 It's hard to say, why it happens, without seeing the actual data in the tables. If you prepare an example of data and explain, how it breaks, I would be able to tell, what's wrong.

Comment: you mean to explore my tables  with fields??

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the most granular data to show, your conditional structure needs to be as follows, otherwise it will execute each of them that is satisfied.

```
if ($_POST['listbyqb']=="by_city") {...}
else if ($_POST['listbyqa']=="by_district") {...}
else if ($_POST['listbyq']=="by_ governorate") {...}
else {...}
```